# Bootstrap 3 two overlaying modals

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I'd like two overlapping dynamic modals and when I close the second modal the original one keep open. I try to catch the second one's hide.bs.modal and hidden.bs.modal events to close it but those don't trigger just on the first modal.
But when I catch the original modal hide.bs.modal event and I want to close the second modal

> $("#second").modal('hide');

it throws an error:

> Invalid regular expression: /(^|.)bs.(?:.*.|)modal(.|$)/: Stack
>   overflow

```
$("#original").on('hide.bs.modal', function (event) {
   if($("#second").is(':visible')) 
   {
      $("#second").modal('hide');
      event.stopPropagation();
      return false;
   }
};
```

How can I do it, please?

**UPDATE:**
The two modals have the same z-index = 1050. I think those should be different numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Moved solution from question to answer:

> **UPDATE2:**
>   The solution:
>   the second modal was nested in the first one and when I took out it the error ceased.